# Urbit error: Assertion '!"plan: no pier"' failed in vere/pier.c:2091

Tags: urbit

I downloaded urbit and am attempting to boot my ship for the first time. In following the instructions online, I ran the following command:
`./urbit -w sampel-palnet -k path/to/my-planet.key`

The script progressed until this line:
`boot: downloading pill https://bootstrap.urbit.org/urbit-v0.10.4.pill`
After some time, I received the error in the title of this question.

Does anyone know what the error means and what I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking [this issue on Github](https://github.com/urbit/urbit/issues/1961). It's not exactly the same error as yours, but it's similar, so maybe it could be related.

Did you also check the [Urbit Docs](https://urbit.org/docs/tutorials/ship-troubleshooting/).

If none of this works I would recommend you [create an issue](https://github.com/urbit/urbit/issues/new/choose) in Urbit's Github page.